# How to join two tables with repetitive unique factor

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, many-to-many

I'm having difficulty to join these two tables, unfortunately, I'm working mis-structured database build in sql server

```
    equipment Serial number | client   | equipment check out date  | equipment check in date
    nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852     | john     | 19991231                  | 20000308
    nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852     | sami     | 20000315                  | 20000828
    nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852     | john     | 20000902                  | 20010221
```

---

```
    equipment Serial number |start maintenance date |   finish maintenance date |   maintenance cost
     nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852    |   20000202            |   20000206                | 98.65
     nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852    |   20000310            |   20000312                | 10.85
     nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852    |   20000828            |   20000902                | 60.97
     nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852    |   20000902            |   20000903                | 15.88
```

Is there any possibility to calculate the maintenance cost per client?
it is many to many
there are only two factors "serial number" and "dates duration",
serial numbers are repetitive
I have a hard to match the duration

Comment: What do you expect as output from this?

Comment: Is it really many-to-many? If one piece of equipment can't be checked out more than one, it's not many-to-many I think. Join the tables on Serial number, and Check Out date < Start Maintenance and Check In date > Finish Maintenance. Or <=, depending on the data/needs.

Comment: Can the client start maintenance even equipment is not check out? I cannot match cost for 10.85 and 60.97 Give us some logic here.

Comment: check out date <= start maintenance and next check out date > end maintenance date

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the maintenance is associated with only one client, you can do this as a `join`:

```
select t1.client, sum(t2.cost)
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.esn = t2.esn and t1.ecodate >= t2.startdate and t1.ecodate < t2.enddate
group by t1.client;
```

If the maintenance spans clients, I would suggest that you ask *another* question with appropriate sample data and a very clear description of how to apportion such costs.

Comment: `t2.ecodate < t2.enddate` should be `t1.ecodate < t2.enddate`

Comment: I will try this

Comment: check out date <= start maintenance and next check out date > end maintenance date

Answer (score 2):

This is about what you want, but you may have to adjust the formula because you have at least one overlapping date in your sample data which I'm not sure if the cost should be associated with John, or Sami and it's currently attributed to both.

```
DECLARE @ClientRental TABLE (Serial varchar(50),client varchar(50), CheckOutDate date, CheckInDate date)
INSERT INTO @ClientRental
    select 'nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852','john','19991231', '20000308'
    union
    select 'nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852','sami','20000315', '20000828'
    union
    select 'nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852','john','20000902', '20010221'

DECLARE @Maintenance TABLE (Serial varchar(50), StartMaintainDate date, FinishMaintainDate date, cost decimal(12,2))   
INSERT INTO @Maintenance
    select 'nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852','20000202', '20000206', 98.65
    union
    select 'nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852','20000310', '20000312', 10.85
    union
    select 'nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852','20000828', '20000902', 60.97
    union
    select 'nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852','20000902', '20000903', 15.88

Select CR.Serial, CR.client, m.cost
from @ClientRental CR
LEFT JOIN @Maintenance M on (
        ((CheckOutDate <= FinishMaintainDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= CheckInDate) and (CheckOutDate <= CheckInDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= FinishMaintainDate)) 
        or ((CheckOutDate <= FinishMaintainDate) and (CheckOutDate <= CheckInDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= CheckInDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= FinishMaintainDate))
        )

Select CR.Serial, CR.client, SUM(m.cost)
from @ClientRental CR
LEFT JOIN @Maintenance M on (
        ((CheckOutDate <= FinishMaintainDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= CheckInDate) and (CheckOutDate <= CheckInDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= FinishMaintainDate)) 
        or ((CheckOutDate <= FinishMaintainDate) and (CheckOutDate <= CheckInDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= CheckInDate) and (StartMaintainDate <= FinishMaintainDate))
        )
GROUP BY CR.Serial, CR.client
```

First Results:

```
nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852|john|98.65
nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852|john|60.97
nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852|john|15.88
nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852|sami|60.97
```

Second Results:

```
nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852|john|175.50
nzxi-1565-ubbi-4852|sami|60.97
```

Comment: check out date <= start maintenance and next check out date > end maintenance date